# R Variance Inflation Factors - Warning : No function found corresponding to methods exports from ‘SparseM’ for: ‘coerce’

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-car

I am playing around with the car library for R and have encountered the following warning after calling the variance_inflation_factors function on my data model.

> No function found corresponding to methods exports from ‘SparseM’ for:
>   ‘coerce’

This error is the result of the following code

```r
library(car)

data = read.table("path/to/data.txt")
attach(data)

model = lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3)

vif(model)
```

But still yields a regular output shown as

```sh
      X1       X2       X3
1.578524 2.276641 2.021541
```

All together the output appears as

```sh
Warning message:
no function found corresponding to methods exports from ‘SparseM’ for: ‘coerce’
      X1       X2       X3
1.578524 2.276641 2.021541
```

Is my output affected by the lack of the coerce method?

Comment: I had the same warning message when trying to execute an Rscript. Kindly let me know if you found out why the error message is shown.

Answer (score 3):

This was an oversight on my part.  SparseM was exporting a function called
coerce, but there was no such function.  This will be corrected in the new
version 1.7 of SparseM.